# PostgreSQL remote access

Tags: postgresql, remote

I added remote host info on pg_hba.conf as:

```
host db1 all 10.6.169.88/27 trust
```

and also I did

```
listen_addresses = ‘*’
tcpip_socket = true
```

on postgresql.conf.

But still the remote client can not connect to db. What is the missing part about this? Remote client and host server is in different locations but with IT policies adjusted with correct ports and routes. So remote client is normally accessible to host server.

Here is what remote client gets as error:

[image: error on client side]

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get? tcpip_socket is only for local connections to begin with, so that config option is irrelevant for the question

Comment: Did you restart the service?

Comment: I edited the question and added what is the error on clients side.

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ yes I restarted.

Comment: Can you connect to the server by some other means and query "pg_hba_file_rules"?  Can you check the log file on the server, to make sure its error message match the client?

Comment: @jjanes our customer has tried to connect with pg_admin over their compıter remotely again but it did not work. There was not connected error again.

Comment: Based on the data shown taken at face value, I don't see a "real" explanation.  It should work.  I think the problem is that you didn't really reload the conf change, or you edited the wrong pg_hba.conf, or you reloaded the wrong server, or you are connecting to the wrong server, or you are looking at the wrong log file, or something along that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after editing the correct pg-hba.conf file. Well, earlier our customer asked us to move postgresql data to other drive partition. So there are two copies of conf files. One is inside postgresql program folder and the other is in data folder. To achieve what I want I needed to edit the one inside data folder.